# Select row if col1 value exits twice and col2 is not null

Tags: sql, performance, select, subquery, informix

We are monitoring network devices. 
A device may appear at more than one switch.

We want to filter out those devices which are on an uplink / portchannel in case it appears also on another port. All other devices are selected.

Let's say the table looks like:

```
HOST,  SWITCH,  PORT
HostA, Switch1, 01
HostB, Switch1, 02
HostA, Switch2, Po  - Po is portchannel / uplink
HostC, Switch2, Po  - Po is portchannel / uplink
```

Desired Output:

```
HostA, Switch1, 01
HostB, Switch1, 02
HostC, Swtich2, Po  - is only on an uplink / so that is OK
```

The Entry HostA, Switch2, Po needs to be filtered out since it appears on another port as well.

Now the question is how to write an efficient query.

In SQL terms we want to select all rows except those where HOST appears twice. Then we want only that row where PORT is not 'Po'

Our current query is slow because of subqueries !?
I assume that the subquery is creating a cartesian product - right?

```
SELECT * FROM devices t1
WHERE NOT ((Port = 'Po') AND 
      ((Select count(*) from table t2 where t1.host=t2.host AND NOT Port='Po') > 0))
```

Again the question is  how to write a faster SQL query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exists should be faster than correlated count(*)

```
select *
  from devices t1
 where (port <> 'Po'
        or not exists (select null
                         from devices t2
                        where t2.host = t1.host
                          and t2.Port <> 'Po')
       )
```

**UPDATE:** if you think that join version would perform better:

```
select t1.*
  from devices t1
  left join devices t2
    on t1.host = t2.host
   and t2.port <> 'Po'
 where (t1.port <> 'Po'
    or t2.port is null)
```

The query self-joines devices table, removing Po's from second instance. It then proceeds to select all non-Po's and Po's without matching non-Po. Oh well, what an explanation.

Comment: I like that SQL already a lot better. But is there a way to avoid the subquery (e.g. with joins / temp table)

Comment: @ThorstenNiehues Could you please give join query a shot?

Comment: Thanks a lot - looks real good. I'll test both versions today / tomorrow an let you know.

Comment: Runtimes: 1. with select count : 3 sec - 
2. with "not exists" (your first post) 8 sec - 
3. with the "left join" (updated post) 0.2 sec. 
Database is Informix

Comment: @ThorstenNiehues Thanks for the info. I would never expect exists() to be slower than count(*) - well, not the first time I was wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT HOST as HOST,  SWITCH,  PORT from table 
WHERE port<>'po' 
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(HOST) as HOST,  SWITCH,  PORT from table
WHERE port='po'
GROUP BY SWITCH,  PORT
```

Comment: This SQL statement selects only devices on a port-channel. All devices must be selected. If there is a duplicate host then the one on the port-channel must be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is at most one port on a host/switch combination, you can use group by:

```
select HOST, SWITCH,
       (case when max(case when PORT <> 'Po' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
             then max(case when PORT <> 'Po' then port end)
             else 'Po'
        end) port
from t
group by host, switch
```

If you have a database that supports windows functions, you can use:

```
select t.host, t.switch, t.port
from (select t.*,
             sum(isPo) over (partition by host, switch) as numPo,
             count(*) over (partition by host, switch) as numAll
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when port = 'po' then 1 else 0 end) as isPo
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where numPo = numAll or -- all are Po
      (port <> 'Po')    -- remove any other Pos
```